# Google Chrome's passwords.txt is full of words that I don't want on my computer - can I delete it? Will it just return again?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords

I keep a lot of information for myself, (e.g. to-do lists, helpful links, instructions) in .txt files and search my system for keywords to find them.

Recently I started getting `passwords.txt` in my searches and when I checked it out I found it in `/Users/(computername)/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/(hashed)Data/3`

(Chrome Version 110.0.5481.100 (Official Build) (x86_64), I use macOS)

It's exactly 30,000 lines long and ~240 kB in size and is full of words I don't want on my computer<sup>1</sup>. Words tend to be short and look like bad but popular choices for passwords, often of a biological nature.

Can someone help me understand why it's there, whether I can delete it, and if it will just return again if I do?

---

<sup>1</sup>at least in the form of searchable text - hashed  or some kind of binary encoding wouldn't bother me

Comment: and by words you don't want on your computer, do we mean profanity and other such naughty words?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's certainly one reason, but there are also terms that conflict with my searching. For example, I do molecular dynamics calculations and I describe (to myself at least) some of they types of motion in terms that may overlap with such naughty words. But what I'm really after is the question as asked - *can I delete it this file, and will it just return if I do?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### zxcvbn Data Component

The file 'passwords.txt' is part of the [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) password strength estimator that was [added to Chrome in 2020](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/components/metrics/+/d59e49b0732b95cf05357db68bdf0ecd0211a0c1). If removed, the file will be recreated by Chrome.

The file contains about 30,000 strings including common passwords, names, and popular words that form  part of the process zxcvbn uses to rate password complexity.

zxcvbn was presented at the [USENIX 2016](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/wheeler) Security Symposium as an alternative to password composition policies like LUDS (*Counts of **L**ower and **U**ppercase letters, **D**igits and **S**ymbols*).

The developers believe that shifting the focus from rules based on **character requirements** (LUDS) to instead focus on  **password complexity** (zxcvbn) is both more secure as well as more user friendly.

##### Resources

- **YouTube:**   [zxcvbn Presentation](https://youtu.be/vf37jh3dV2I)
- **GitHub:**  [dropbox/zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn)
- **USENIX:**   [2016 Security Symposium](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/wheeler)
- **Wikipedia:**   [Password Strength](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength)

Comment: Oh! the folder name containing "zxcvbn" is not a hash, it's a... thing. Okay this is a (personally) disappointing but conclusive answer.

Comment: I understand.  I'm not a MacOS guy, but in Windows a file or folder can be excluded from search indexing.  Perhaps there is a similar option in MacOS  that would eliminate it from being indexed and thus not returned in search results.

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure there is/are ways to do manage indexing, good points!